# Populate a Pandas SparseDataFrame from a SciPy Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pandas, sparse-matrix

I noticed Pandas now has [support for Sparse Matrices and Arrays](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/sparse.html).  Currently, I create `DataFrame()`s like this:

```
return DataFrame(matrix.toarray(), columns=features, index=observations)
```

Is there a way to create a `SparseDataFrame()` with a `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix()` or `csr_matrix()`? Converting to dense format kills RAM badly. Thanks!

Comment: There is now an experimental API: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/sparse.html#interaction-with-scipy-sparse

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A direct conversion is not supported ATM. Contributions are welcome!

Try this, should be ok on memory as the SpareSeries is much like a csc_matrix (for 1 column)
and pretty space efficient

```
In [37]: col = np.array([0,0,1,2,2,2])

In [38]: data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6],dtype='float64')

In [39]: m = csc_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(3,3) )

In [40]: m
Out[40]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [46]: pd.SparseDataFrame([ pd.SparseSeries(m[i].toarray().ravel()) 
                              for i in np.arange(m.shape[0]) ])
Out[46]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  0  4
1  0  0  5
2  2  3  6

In [47]: df = pd.SparseDataFrame([ pd.SparseSeries(m[i].toarray().ravel()) 
                                   for i in np.arange(m.shape[0]) ])

In [48]: type(df)
Out[48]: pandas.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just thinking aloud here, but since the SciPy Sparse formats are really just an array of data and two arrays of indices, could we somehow just pupulate the `SparseDataFrame` with that?

Comment: its best (in the current implementation) to populate per series (column); which then basically creates an internal index (called an int index) or a block index (sort of like bsr/csr) to locate the values. What kinds of operations are you thinking of doing?

Comment: Would this be different for a csr matrix or is this still the recommended way?

Comment: Jeff, using this method doesn't save memory in my case, calling `df.memory_usage().sum()` is the same if I just created the dataframe like so: `pd.DataFrame(mtx.todense())` . If I however add the `to_sparse` method here `pd.DataFrame(mtx.todense()).to_sparse(fill_value=0)` and call `df.memory_usage().sum()` once again it is less. Maybe this is easy to answer but I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: not really sure what you are doing, this was on a quite old version. Try with newer pandas, if not pls open an issue/SO question.

Comment: it is worth to notice the matrix type in your code is csc and it is slow to get a row from it. It is much faster to either convert the whole matrix to CSR format, or use getcol(i) to get a column instead of row method. If you get the column you need to consider that you get the transposed matrix in df.

Answer (score 20):

As of pandas v 0.20.0 you can use the `SparseDataFrame` constructor.

An example from [the pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html#interaction-with-scipy-sparse):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

arr = np.random.random(size=(1000, 5))
arr[arr < .9] = 0
sp_arr = csr_matrix(arr)
sdf = pd.SparseDataFrame(sp_arr)
```

Answer (score -8):

A much shorter version:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(m.toarray())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `toarray()` converts a sparse matrix into a dense matrix, and uses ridiculous amounts of memory.

Comment: It's simple and short code and for my relatively small dataset the memory consumption was an acceptable tradeoff.