# cheapest way to create pandas.DataFrame or pandas.SparseDataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, bigdata, sparse-matrix

Suppose we have a huge and sparse matrix, what would be the cheapest way to fill it into a `pandas.DataFrame`? More specifically, the huge matrix comes from a big dataset that involves lots of dummy variable and the dense version matrix occupies 150Gb+ memory, which is apparently not durable.

I am trying to penetrate the memory management of python.pandas, as a green hand of pandas. The current dilemma is described as following:

- Using dense source matrix and calling `pd.DataFrame` will not cause memory copy. The dense matrix will eat up most space though.
- If using `scipy.csr_matrix`, `pd.DataFrame` doesn't accept it as argument of constructor. Taking a step back, if we resort to `pd.SparseDataFrame`, how can I avoid memory copy?
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818783/populate-a-pandas-sparsedataframe-from-a-scipy-sparse-matrix) presents one great approach to convert a `scipy.csr_matrix` to a `pd.SparseDataFrame`. But the for-loop is so inefficient and it causes memory copy.

Further, I am trying to initialize a `sparseDataFrame` into block of memory and assign the value row-by-row, which ends up with:

```
a = np.random.rand(4,5)
b = pd.DataFrame(a)
c = sparse.csr_matrix(a)
d = pd.SparseDataFrame(index=b.index, columns=b.columns)
elem = pd.SparseSeries(c[2].toarray().ravel())
d.loc[[2]] = [ elem ]  # Got a NotImplementedError.
elem = pd.Series(c[2].toarray().ravel())
b.loc[[2]] = [ elem ]  # Yes.
```

I feel scripting language is decent, undoubtable. But I just need a pointer at this time, maybe.

Any help is appreciated in advance!

Comment: I feel like this could be a related post/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/low-memory-option-in-read-csv/27232309#27232309