# Pandas sparse dataFrame to sparse matrix, without generating a dense matrix in memory

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is there a way to convert from a `pandas.SparseDataFrame` to `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`, without generating a dense matrix in memory?

```
scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(df.values)
```

doesn't work as it generates a dense matrix which is cast to the `csr_matrix`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run this in reverse?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818783/populate-a-pandas-sparsedataframe-from-a-scipy-sparse-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas docs talks about an experimental conversion to scipy sparse, SparseSeries.to_coo:

http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/sparse.html#interaction-with-scipy-sparse

================

edit - this is a special function from a multiindex, not a data frame.  See the other answers for that.  Note the difference in dates.

============

As of 0.20.0, there is a `sdf.to_coo()` and a multiindex `ss.to_coo()`.  Since a sparse matrix is inherently 2d, it makes sense to require multiindex for the (effectively) 1d dataseries.  While the dataframe can represent a table or 2d array.

When I first responded to this question this sparse dataframe/series feature was experimental (june 2015).

Comment: This is only for `MultiIndex`-ed `SparseSeries`, not for a DataFrame.

Comment: As @eleanora mentioned, [this does actually work now](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.SparseDataFrame.to_coo.html#pandas.SparseDataFrame.to_coo) (as of version 0.20.0, released May 5, 2017). `sparse.csr_matrix(df.to_coo())` is the one-liner that will do the trick. Maybe you should edit your answer to make that clear?

Comment: Maybe we should close to topic as dated?

Comment: Is it common to close a perfectly valid question because the answers have become dated? I didn't think that was a thing, and it seems like a bad idea in general.

Comment: It would save me from downvotes because my answer is no longer valid.  Not that it really matters.  :)

Comment: If you think you should remove your *answer* because you're afraid of getting downvotes, you're welcome to. Personally, I would never downvote an answer just because it required an update. I really doubt you're going to get downvotes for this.

Answer (score 15):

## Pandas 0.20.0+:

As of pandas version 0.20.0, released May 5, 2017, there is a one-liner for this:

```
from scipy import sparse


def sparse_df_to_csr(df):
    return sparse.csr_matrix(df.to_coo())
```

This uses the new [`to_coo()` method](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.SparseDataFrame.to_coo.html#pandas.SparseDataFrame.to_coo).

## Earlier Versions:

Building on Victor May's answer, here's a slightly faster implementation, but it only works if the entire `SparseDataFrame` is sparse with all `BlockIndex` (note: if it was created with `get_dummies`, this will be the case).

**Edit**: I modified this so it will work with a non-zero fill value. CSR has no native non-zero fill value, so you will have to record it externally.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse

def sparse_BlockIndex_df_to_csr(df):
    columns = df.columns
    zipped_data = zip(*[(df[col].sp_values - df[col].fill_value,
                         df[col].sp_index.to_int_index().indices)
                        for col in columns])
    data, rows = map(list, zipped_data)
    cols = [np.ones_like(a)*i for (i,a) in enumerate(data)]
    data_f = np.concatenate(data)
    rows_f = np.concatenate(rows)
    cols_f = np.concatenate(cols)
    arr = sparse.coo_matrix((data_f, (rows_f, cols_f)),
                            df.shape, dtype=np.float64)
    return arr.tocsr()
```

Comment: How about using `series.to_coo()` to convert each column, and `sparse.bmat()` to join those into one matrix?

Comment: @hpaulj That sounds like a distinct answer - you should write it up!

Comment: Digging further I see that the Multiindex mapping is very different from simple column vectors I had in mind.  It's more like the feature matrix that `sklearn` people like.

Comment: It seems this works now. dataset = sparse.csr_matrix(df.to_coo())

Answer (score 4):

As of Pandas version 0.25 `SparseSeries` and `SparseDataFrame` are deprecated. DataFrames now support [Sparse Dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/user_guide/sparse.html#sparse-dtypes) for columns with sparse data. Sparse methods are available through `sparse` accessor, so conversion one-liner now looks like this:

```
sparse_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(df.sparse.to_coo())
```

Comment: A follow-up question is: How to convert categorical columns with a large number of values to `Sparse Dtypes` efficiently?  `pd.get_dummies(df, sparse = True)` takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @Marigold does the trick, but it is slow due to accessing all elements in each column, including the zeros. Building on it, I wrote the following quick n' dirty code, which runs about 50x faster on a 1000x1000 matrix with a density of about 1%. My code also handles dense columns appropriately.

```
def sparse_df_to_array(df):
    num_rows = df.shape[0]   

    data = []
    row = []
    col = []

    for i, col_name in enumerate(df.columns):
        if isinstance(df[col_name], pd.SparseSeries):
            column_index = df[col_name].sp_index
            if isinstance(column_index, BlockIndex):
                column_index = column_index.to_int_index()

            ix = column_index.indices
            data.append(df[col_name].sp_values)
            row.append(ix)
            col.append(len(df[col_name].sp_values) * [i])
        else:
            data.append(df[col_name].values)
            row.append(np.array(range(0, num_rows)))
            col.append(np.array(num_rows * [i]))

    data_f = np.concatenate(data)
    row_f = np.concatenate(row)
    col_f = np.concatenate(col)

    arr = coo_matrix((data_f, (row_f, col_f)), df.shape, dtype=np.float64)
    return arr.tocsr()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that fills the sparse matrix column by column (assumes you can fit at least one column to memory).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix

def sparse_df_to_array(df):
    """ Convert sparse dataframe to sparse array csr_matrix used by
    scikit learn. """
    arr = lil_matrix(df.shape, dtype=np.float32)
    for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
        ix = df[col] != 0
        arr[np.where(ix), i] = df.ix[ix, col]

    return arr.tocsr()
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: This method is actually having a dense representation at some stage, so it doesn't solve the question.

You should be able to use the experimental `.to_coo()` method in pandas [1] in the following way:

```
df, idx_rows, idx_cols = df.stack().to_sparse().to_coo()
df = df.tocsr()
```

This method, instead of taking a `DataFrame` (rows / columns) it takes a `Series` with rows and columns in a `MultiIndex` (this is why you need the `.stack()` method). This `Series` with the `MultiIndex` needs to be a `SparseSeries`, and even if your input is a `SparseDataFrame`, `.stack()` returns a regular `Series`. So, you need to use the `.to_sparse()` method before calling `.to_coo()`.

The `Series` returned by `.stack()`, even if it's not a `SparseSeries` only contains the elements that are not null, so it shouldn't take more memory than the sparse version (at least with `np.nan` when the type is `np.float`).

1. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html#interaction-with-scipy-sparse

Comment: This method seems to use a huge amount of memory sadly.

Comment: You're right @eleanora, not sure how I tested it before, but it looks like internally this method has a dense internal representation of the array, so it's pointless for the question. Sorry for the wrong answer.

Comment: It seems this works now. `dataset =  sparse.csr_matrix(df.to_coo())`