# Create sparse matrix in CSR/COO format for a huge feature vector from categorical data stored in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, scipy, statistics

How do I create a sparse matrix in CSR/COO format for a huge feature vector (50000 x 100000) from categorical data stored in Pandas DataFrame? I am creating the feature vector using Pandas get_dummies() function, but it returns a MemoryError. How do I avoid that and rather generate it in a sparse matrix CSR format?

Comment: Pandas has a sparse format, and experimental way of generating a `scipy` sparse matrix (something like `tocoo()`.  Most likely the memory error is the result creating a large dense array as intermediary.  Do an SO search.

Comment: What do you mean by an SO search? Also, the to_coo seems to be a method for a SparseSeries object and not a SparseDataFrame. How do I go around doing it for a SparseDataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly useful links:

[Populate a Pandas SparseDataFrame from a SciPy Sparse Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818783/populate-a-pandas-sparsedataframe-from-a-scipy-sparse-matrix)

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.SparseSeries.to_coo.html#pandas.SparseSeries.to_coo

[Pandas sparse dataFrame to sparse matrix, without generating a dense matrix in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084942/pandas-sparse-dataframe-to-sparse-matrix-without-generating-a-dense-matrix-in-m)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(df_dummies)
```

but do not forget to create df_dummies **sparse** in the first place...

```
df_dummies = pandas.get_dummies(df, sparse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer will keep the data as sparse as possible and avoids memory issues when using Pandas get_dummies.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from scipy import sparse

df = pd.DataFrame({'rowid':[1,2,3,4,5], 'category':['c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c3', 'c1']})

print 'Input data frame\n{0}'.format(df)

print 'Encode column category as numerical variables'
print LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df.category)

print 'Encode column category as dummy matrix'
print OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df.category).reshape(-1,1)).todense()

print 'Concat with the original data frame as a matrix'
dummy_matrix = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df.category).reshape(-1,1))
df_as_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix(df.drop(labels=['category'], axis=1).as_matrix())
sparse_combined = sparse.hstack((df_as_sparse, dummy_matrix), format='csr')
print sparse_combined.todense()
```