# Convert Pandas SparseDataframe to Scipy sparse csc_matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I want to convert a pandas `SparseDataFrame` to a `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix`. But I don't want to convert it back to a dense matrix first.

Right now I have something like the below.

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, sparse=True)
```

Basically what I need is to further get a `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix` from `df`. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @hpaulj's reply. I ended it up using the template from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38157234/7298911.

Here is the modified implementation.

```
def sparseDfToCsc(df):
    columns = df.columns
    dat, rows = map(list,zip(*[(df[col].sp_values-df[col].fill_value, df[col].sp_index.to_int_index().indices) for col in columns]))
    cols = [np.ones_like(a)*i for (i,a) in enumerate(dat)]
    datF, rowsF, colsF = np.concatenate(dat), np.concatenate(rows), np.concatenate(cols)
    arr = sparse.coo_matrix((datF, (rowsF, colsF)), df.shape, dtype=np.float64)
    return arr.tocsc()

df = pd.get_dummies(df, sparse=True)
cscMatrix = sparseDfToCsc(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've participated in various sparse Pandas to scipy sparce questions.

There is a Pandas method for converting a multiindex sparse series to coo matrix:

http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/sparse.html#interaction-with-scipy-sparse

But see [Pandas sparse dataFrame to sparse matrix, without generating a dense matrix in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084942/pandas-sparse-dataframe-to-sparse-matrix-without-generating-a-dense-matrix-in-m)
for data frame to sparse.

and

[How do I create a scipy sparse matrix from a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084032/how-do-i-create-a-scipy-sparse-matrix-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

and more recently, [How can I "sparsify" on two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594514/how-can-i-sparsify-on-two-values)

Once you have a `coo` matrix, you can easily convert it to `csr` or `csc`.

To avoid confusion I'd suggest creating a sample dataframe, convert to dense and then to sparse.  That we have something concrete to test.  I used to recommend the Pandas method, without realizing that MultiIndex was different from DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @hpaulj. If I understand you correctly, the best approach should be [Pandas sparse dataFrame to sparse matrix, without generating a dense matrix in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084942/pandas-sparse-dataframe-to-sparse-matrix-without-generating-a-dense-matrix-in-m). Right?