# Is there a way to form sparse n-dimensional array in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am pretty new to Python and have been wondering if there an easy way so that I could form a sparse n-dimensional array M in Python3 with following 2 conditions mainly required (along the lines of SciPy COO_Matrix):

1. M[dim1,dim2,dim3,...] = 1.0
2. Like SciPy COO_Matrix M: M.row, M.col, I may be able to get all the row and column indices for which non-zero entries exist in the matrix. In N-dimension, this generalizes to calling: M.1 for 1st dimension, M.2 for 2nd dimension and so on...

For 2-dimension (the 2 conditions):

```
 1.
     for u, i in data:
        mat[u, i] = 1.0

 2. def get_triplets(mat):
        return mat.row, mat.col
```

Can these 2 conditions be generalized in N-dimensions? I searched and came across this:

[sparse 3d matrix/array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685128/sparse-3d-matrix-array-in-python)

But here 2nd condition is not satisfied: In other words, I can't get the all the nth dimensional indices in a vectorized format.

Also this:
http://www.janeriksolem.net/sparray-sparse-n-dimensional-arrays-in.html works for python and not python3.

Is there a way to implement n-dimensional arrays with above mentioned 2 conditions satisfied? Or I am over-complicating things? I appreciate any help with this :)

Comment: You could certainly create a data structure modeled on either `coo` (column per dimension) or `dok`.  And you could fill it in a way that meets your conditions.  But whether you can do anything useful with it (multiplication, display, etc) without doing a lot of coding is a tougher question.  For a start, demonstrate your conditions using the `scipy.sparse` 2d code.

Comment: Scipy has different ways to initialize sparse matrices- and they can be converted into each other. But you seem to look for a matrix that is sparse but with 1 being the value of any sparse element. That won't work at all as the optimizations of sparse matrices are based on the fact that sparse cells are zero.

Comment: @hpaulj, I edited based on your comment. Hope its a bit clearer now. I am reading your answer now.

Comment: @RuDevel, I did not mean that. M is sparse N-dimensional sparse array with non-zero values as 1.0 and all other values as 0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of `coo` format I could generate a 3d sparse array representation:

```
In [106]: dims = 2,4,6
In [107]: data = np.zeros((10,4),int)
In [108]: data[:,-1] = 1
In [112]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     data[:,i] = np.random.randint(0,dims[i],10)

In [113]: data
Out[113]: 
array([[0, 2, 3, 1],
       [0, 3, 4, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 3, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 3, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 5, 1],
       [0, 1, 5, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 1]])
```

Does that meet your requirements?  It's possible there are some duplicates.  `sparse.coo` sums duplicates before it converts the array to dense for display, or to `csr` for calculations.

The corresponding dense array is:

```
In [130]: A=np.zeros(dims, int)
In [131]: for row in data:
     ...:     A[tuple(row[:3])] += row[-1]

In [132]: A
Out[132]: 
array([[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

(no duplicates in this case).

A 2d sparse matrix using a subset of this data is

```
In [118]: sparse.coo_matrix((data[:,3],(data[:,1],data[:,2])),(4,6)).A
Out[118]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

That's in effect the sum over the first dimension.

---

I'm assuming that

```
M[dim1,dim2,dim3,...] = 1.0
```

means the non-zero elements of the array must have a data value of 1.

Pandas has a sparse data series and data frame format.  That allows for a non-zero 'fill' value.  I don't know if the multi-index version can be thought of as higher than 2d or not.  There have been a few SO questions about converting the Pandas sparse arrays to/from the scipy sparse.

[Convert Pandas SparseDataframe to Scipy sparse csc_matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152264/convert-pandas-sparsedataframe-to-scipy-sparse-csc-matrix)

http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/sparse.html#interaction-with-scipy-sparse