# Why does it take so long to create a SparseDataFrame (Python pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, jupyter

Given the following code (executed in a Jupyter notebook):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        %time df=pd.SparseDataFrame(index=range(0,1000), columns=range(0,1000));

CPU times: user 3.89 s, sys: 30.3 ms, total: 3.92 s
Wall time: 3.92 s
```

Why does it take so long to create a sparse data frame?

Note that it seems to be irrelevant if I increse the dimension for the rows. But when I increase the number of columns from 1000 to say 10000, the code seems to take forever and I always had to abort it.

Compare this with scipy's sparse matrix:

```
In [2]: from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
        %time m=lil_matrix((1000, 1000))

CPU times: user 1.09 ms, sys: 122 µs, total: 1.21 ms
Wall time: 1.18 ms
```

Comment: That `lil_matrix` is just an empty one.  It has a shape, but no values.

Comment: I've participated in SO questions about creating a sparse matrix from a sparse data frame.  The required code might give you a sense of how involved it is.  I believe a sparse data frame consists of one sparse data series per column.  Evidently the columns are converted individually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084942/pandas-sparse-dataframe-to-sparse-matrix-without-generating-a-dense-matrix-in-m

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16773