# Convert a large 2d-dict to scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 2d dictionary as follow:

```
myDict = {
    "AIK":{"dfa":1,"bff":2,"mam":1},
    "BQQ":{"dic":5,"mam":8,"nzz":3},
    "ZZD":{"gox":6,"xee":2,"dic":9}
}
```

The length of `myDict.keys()` is 5000 and the sum of inner keys is 10000
How can I convert it to **a scipy sparse matrix (5000,10000)** as fast as possible

Comment: There is a `dok` format that is a dictionary subclass.  For the key values are a tuple, `(i,j)`, row and column index.   But to generate that you'd have map all main keys to `range(5000)`, and all inner keys to `range(10000)`.  But given the need to iterate over 2 dictionary levels the conversion will not be fast or pretty.

Comment: If you go the SparseDataFrame route, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084942/pandas-sparse-dataframe-to-sparse-matrix-without-generating-a-dense-matrix-in-m for conversion information.