# MemoryError Issue in scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have **scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix** object size of (118723, 20748) when I am trying to convert it into an array by using toarray() function it giving me *** MemoryError:

Please find below my code:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5,stop_words='english')
X = tfidf.fit_transform(sentance_list)
sentanceDF=pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(),columns=tfidf.get_feature_names())
```

Error:

```
*** MemoryError:
```

Please help me to resole this issue.

Comment: That will need > 18 GB memory.

Comment: @sascha Is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Keep it sparse. What's possible depends on pandas and your use-case. But a dense matrix of size (118723, 20748) will always need ```2463264804*x-bits``` of memory (e.g. x=64 four double).

Comment: try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818783/populate-a-pandas-sparsedataframe-from-a-scipy-sparse-matrix. Looks like a potential work around but I can't say for sure ow much RAM it will eat.